# Django + Susy или Django + Bootstrap? Или другой вариант?

Tags: django, bootstrap, angularjs, sass, django-rest-framework

Добрый день! Использую Django + Angular + Django REST.
Необходимо динамически размещать изображения разного размера плиткой, с возможностью перемещения их посредством drag-n-drop. Для размещения использую сейчас bootstrap.js, а для перетаскивания
Sortable.js + ng-sortable.js git:://github.com/rubaxa/Sortable.git
Но возникает проблема с картинками разного размера, возникает ситуация подобная этой

[image: Bootstrap и изображения разного размера]

А нужно, чтобы было несколько колонок, и каждая картинка могла занимать одну или несколько колонок, в зависимости от размера картинки. 
Что-то вроде этого (представим, что каждый блок - это картинка):

[image: Шаблон для блоков разного размера]

Пример для Susy с их сайта вроде ближе к тому, что должно быть:
[image: Макет сайта]

Но до конца не уверен, подойдет ли мне этот фреймоворк для решения данной задачи?
Установил `sudo gem install sass, sudo gem install susy, pip install libsass`. Что еще нужно установить и как использовать susy для django сайта?
Для Zend фреймворка нашел мануал: http://zencoder.ru/susy/brief-tutorial-susy-2/
Как мне сделать аналогичное для Django? При помощи susy или предложите, пожалуйста, лучший вариант. По поводу susy не уверен.

**Обновление:**
Установил еще `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev, sudo gem install compass`.

Где подключать вот это, и в каком виде для Django?

```
@import "normalize";
@import "compass";
@import "susy";
```

**Обновление 2:**
Установил `sudo pip install django-compass2`, в settings.py добавил:

```
COMPASS_INPUT = BASE_DIR + 'media/sass'
COMPASS_OUTPUT = BASE_DIR + 'media/css'
COMPASS_STYLE = 'compact'
COMPASS_REQUIRES = (
    'ninesixty',  # 960.gs Grid System
)
```

и 'djcompass' в  INSTALLED_APPS.
Создал папки media/sass, media/css

При выполнении `python manage.py compass`
не находит модуль 'djcompass'.

**Обновление 3:**
пока закомментировал djcompass в INSTALLED_APPS.
Добавил в settings.py:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/scss', 'sass --scss {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

В шаблоне:

```
{% load compress %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% compress css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="{% static 'styles.scss' %}" />
{% endcompress %}
```

Ругается: `'compress' is not a valid tag library`
Гугл говорит, что нужно сделать что-то вроде

```
compass create [folder] -r rest-foundation --using foundation
```

Но compass мне не удалось настроить.
И не совсем понятно, для susy/compass/sass необходимо создавать отдельный проект внутри проекта django? Пока не понимаю, как их всех вместе скрестить, чтобы работало: **Django + Django REST + Angular + SASS + Compass (и непонятно, можно ли обойтись без него?) + Susy.**

**Обновление 4:**
`sass -v` выдает `Sass 3.4.18 (Selective Steve)`

Установил pip install django-compressor
на основе этого http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/
В settings добавил

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    # other finders..
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

Добавил в INSTALLED_APPS "compressor" - после этого 500 ошибка.

При добавлении в TEMPLATES OPTIONS
`django.templatetags.compress и django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.compress` пишет, что у таких модулей нет "compress" attribute/class

**Обновление 5:** нашел angular-gridster.js, который размещает вроде как нужно, + поддерживает drag-n-drop http://manifestwebdesign.github.io/angular-gridster/?utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation
На этапе до sass/susy/compass:

```
bower install angular-gridster

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-gridster/dist/angular-gridster.min.css"/>
    <script src="bower_components/javascript-detect-element-resize/jquery.resize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-gridster/dist/angular-gridster.min.js"></script>

Обновление 6
```

Подключил по мануалу на сайте разработчика, все работает. Единственная проблема - как настроить angular-gripster, чтобы убрать z-слои и наложение изображений друг на друга?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы подключил [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). И в "бутстрапе", и в "susy", проблемы выравнивания блоков с разной высотой есть и будут. А "masonry" справится.

Также рекомендую по возможности избавиться от "compass" - он перестал активно развиваться пару лет назад. Если нужна альтернатива - попробуйте [bourbon](http://bourbon.io/).